# I cannot get pure text from a div with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a div with text like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">Get this text</div>
```

I have tried the following methods:

```
var $var2 = $('#myDiv').text();

var div = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var $var2 = div.textContent; // white space/block around text
var $var2 = div.innerHTML; // same as textContent
```

I think I've tried others but that's what I can remember at the moment.

I've also seen this answer, but I'm not sure if it is necessary/applies to my case.

```
$("strong")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();    //get the text of element
```

I'm sending two variables in a `$.post` call and `$var2` is always blank unless I specify directly something like `$var2 = "text";`

When I alert the two variables say $var1 and $var2 side by side, $var2 is pushed away form $var1 unless I declare `$var2 = "text";` in which case they are side by side. Then the insert goes through, `$var2` is not blank.

I'm thinking I may just use a hidden input field and set the value of that with this div label so that my insert can still go through.

Comment: So what is your issue again?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, the text selected is not pure text, there's space around it, and isn't accepted by insert into MySQL database with PHP. This variable is blank.

Comment: Than trim the whitespaces using `$.trim( $("#myDiv").text() )`

Comment: Adds snippet, and identify where things are going wrong that we may help, instead of starting a long Q/A with you

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan holy crap that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the text selected is not pure text, there's space around it, and isn't accepted by insert into MySQL database with PHP. This variable is blank

**Trim the whitespaces** using

```
var value = $.trim( $("#myDiv").text() );
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

---

In JS ES5 you can use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

```
var value = document.getElementById("myDiv").textContent.trim();
```

Comment: This is the answer, I have to wait 6 minutes to accept haha

Comment: this trim all whitespaces, not just around

Comment: @SalathielGenèse nope. All it takes is to read the docs: `Description: Remove the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string.`

Answer (score -1):

Just add this:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText
```

or

```
(document.getElementById('myDiv').textContent+"").trim()
```

Comment: To be honest whit you i think that exist something very wrong in your page for they dont accept the innerText.
use this instead:
(document.getElementById('myDiv').textContent+"").trim()

Comment: The div looks just like what I posted above, no need for the rest of the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (Unless the target Node is `document` [documentElement]) the `+""` is not needed since `Node.textContent` returns a String.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) core method
Then, using [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to trim

```
$('#myDiv').html().replace(/^\w*(.*)\w*$/, '$1')
```